# Can you implicitly call a method based on an object

Tags: c++

I have written a to_string() method for a class I am working on. It is supposed to be used with an operator overload to print a class object. But if I do something like this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << Jd(0.5);
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( oss.str(), std::string("JD 0.5") );
```

Instead of calling my to_string() function, it will cast to another operator overload i have for another class. Is there a way I can link 
my to_string to implicitly print Jd objects even if it isnt directly calling a to_string()? Here's my to_string() method as well:

```
std::string Jd::to_string() const {

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "JD " << jd_;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `operator<<` for `Jd` and let it call your `to_string()` function

```
std::ostringstream& operator<<(std::ostringstream& os, const Jd& jd)
{
  os << jd.to_string();
  return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should overload the stream insertion operator (`<<`) for your `Jd` class.

```
class Jd
{
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Jd&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Jd& obj)
{
   out << "JD " << obj.jd_;
   return out;
}
```

If you don't want to make the `operator<<()` function a friend, simply call `obj.to_string()` instead of directly accessing the `obj.jd_` member.